# Series, an problem with a convergence tests i think series is convergent.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Good morning, i need help with this series.

$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }{\frac {2+\sin \left( n \right) }{\sqrt [3]{{n}^{
4}+1}}}$

I applied the next test convergence:

$-1\leq sen(n)\leq1$

$1\leq sen(n)+2\leq3$

$\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{n^{4}+1}}\leq\frac{sen(n)+2}{\sqrt[3]{n^{4}+1}}\leq\frac{3}{\sqrt[3]{n^{4}+1}}$

$lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{3}{\sqrt[3]{n^{4}+1}}=0$

and now, my serie is convergent, but... i don't know, it's all fine? can i make this?

Comment: You have shown that the terms in the sum converge to zero, but that is not enough to show that the sum itself converges.

Comment: why? i don't understand... @angryavian

Answer (score 1):

You second-to-last step will be (almost) enough for you to conclude directly, by comparison with the (convergent, as $\frac{4}{3} >  1$) $p$-series $\sum_n \frac{1}{n^{4/3}}$:

$$
0 \leq \frac{\sin n + 2 }{(n^4+1)^{1/3}} \leq \frac{3}{n^{4/3}}
$$

However, the last step you write, while still technically true, will not give you the conclusion you want: it shows the general term of the series goes to zero, which is a *necessary* condition for the series to converge: but it is not *sufficient* to conclude the series converges. (Indeed, for instance $\frac{1}{n}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} 0$, but $\sum_{n=1 }^\infty\frac{1}{n}$ is a divergent series.)